# SQL - Correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, database

I have problems in understanding this correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Country, CustomerID,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Customers AS CustomersInner
    WHERE CustomersInner.CustomerID < CustomersOuter.CustomerID
    AND CustomersInner.Country=CustomersOuter.Country) + 1
AS customer_seq_num
FROM Customers AS CustomersOuter ORDER BY Country;
```

This example is from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

How does this query work exactly? Why is there a comparison between CustomersInner.CustomerID < CustomersOuter.CustomerID ? And how can the +1 be explained? A deeper explanation would be great.

Comment: In most databases, you would use `rank()` for this purpose.  I would suggest that you study window functions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correlated subquery is executed for every row in the main query. In this case, main query is

```
SELECT Country, CustomerID
  FROM Customers As CustomersOuter
 ORDER BY Country
```

This query returns all customers IDs order by country.

```
Country   | Customer ID
-----------------------
Argentina | 12
Argentina | 54
Argentina | 64
Austria   | 20
Austria   | 59
```

Correlated subquery is executed for each country / customerID pair. In this case:

**For first row:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Customers AS CustomersInner
 WHERE CustomersInner.CustomerID < 12
   AND CustomersInner.Country='Argentina') + 1
```

As there's not a Customer with ID < 12 in Argentina `count(*)` returns zero with +1 you get 1

**For second row:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Customers AS CustomersInner
 WHERE CustomersInner.CustomerID < 54
   AND CustomersInner.Country='Argentina') + 1
```

result will be 1 (customerID = 12) + 1 = 2

and so on...

When you change the Country, the `count(*)` begins again in zero, so you have a running counter: for each country counts the number of customers.

```
Country   | Customer ID | customer_seq_num
------------------------------------------
Argentina | 12          | 1
Argentina | 54          | 2
Argentina | 64          | 3
Austria   | 20          | 1    <--- change country, reset counter (no customerID < 20 in 'Austria')
Austria   | 59          | 2
```